# Xamarin Visual Studio 2012 Activation Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.ios

somehow, Xamarin from Visual Studio 2012 asked to activate my account,

but it give me following errors, anyone knows the workarounds? thanks in advance for your help.

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>d__100.MoveNext()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep step)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass11.<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>b__12(Task t)
```

Comment: Could I ask, why VS2012?

Comment: You should really consider moving to a newer version of VS if you want to do mobile dev.

Answer (score 0):

According to [System Requirements in Xamarin's documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements). The minimal requirements is to run Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

I highly suggest you get at least Visual Studio 2015 or even better 2017, so you can leverage all the great language goodies C#6 and C#7 provides.